# Is it possible to run Corona SDK on ReactOS or Wine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, wine, reactos

I dumped Windows, I'm now using Xubuntu. Is it possible to run [Corona SDK](http://coronalabs.com/) on Wine? On Corona forums, they say no, but I wounder [how this guy did it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896366/debugging-corona-sdk-project-on-linux-from-zerobrane-studio)? Is [ZeroBrane](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) a solution?

What about [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org/) *(or any other open source Windows based OS)*? Is it possible to run Corona Sdk on ReactOS in Virtualbox?

Comment: You can install things like [Android SDK](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-on-ubuntu) natively in Ubuntu,,,

Comment: @wilf I know, I have android SDK installed but some clients want Corona, some of them have created games using Corona and they want me to add features to existing games

Comment: As the link to SO shows, that guy is having problems running Corona SDK on wine. I suggest you instead using a VM instead if you need it.

Comment: @Braiam true this guy had problem, but at least the simulator worked, his issues have to do with Zerobrane not Corona as indicated in his question. Creating a VM? yes, it's an option, which bring me to the next question, would it run on ReactOS?